# How to install mbstring extension

Tags: php, centos6, mbstring

When I installed mbstring in Centos, I got the following error message.

```
# yum install php-mbstring
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vastspace.net
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
 * extras: mirror.vastspace.net
 * updates: mirror.vastspace.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6 for package:php-mbstring-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Installed: php-common-5.4.35-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.35-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Anyone can tell me how I can install mbstring ??

My PHP version : PHP 5.4.35 (cli) (built: Nov 14 2014 07:04:10) on Centos 6.6

Thank you in advance...

Comment: hahaha, i was also struggling with the same problem (in some forums it says we need to re-compile the Extensions),hope some one answers this

Comment: you should ask this question on serverFault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
yum install php-mbstring --enablerepo=remi
```

I installed php-mbstring using remi with this command.
After running that, Restarting Apache service is required.

Answer (score 0):

To search the right MB-String for your PHP version try this command:

```
sudo yum list | egrep 'php' | grep 50
```

Change (50) by the specific version of PHP you do have installed in your server,this command will show you all the packages related to you PHP version.

This command will show :

```
 ea-php50-php-mbstring.x86_64
```

Now you can install the version compatible with your system.I hope it will works for you.