# How to install mbstring on CentOS after upgrade to PHP 7

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, composer-php, mbstring

First,

**PHP version**: PHP 7.0.18 &
**distro**: CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) 
I am a sudo user.

I am setting up a [Themosis](https://framework.themosis.com/) Wordpress install, and I have all of the apache config stuff working great.

Themosis uses [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to manage dependencies. The issue I'm having is when I run `composer install` in the root of my application. What's supposed to happen is that composer installs everything I need for the site, which includes a vendor folder, and a folder called cms with a Wordpress installation. What I actually get is this:

```
 Problem 1
    - illuminate/database v5.5.0 requires illuminate/support 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.5.0, v5.5.2].
    - illuminate/database v5.5.2 requires illuminate/support 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.5.0, v5.5.2].
    - illuminate/database v5.4.0 requires illuminate/support 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/database v5.4.13 requires illuminate/support 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/database v5.4.17 requires illuminate/support 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/database v5.4.19 requires illuminate/support 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/database v5.4.27 requires illuminate/support 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/database v5.4.36 requires illuminate/support 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/database v5.4.9 requires illuminate/support 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/database v5.3.0 requires illuminate/support 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
    - illuminate/database v5.3.16 requires illuminate/support 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
    - illuminate/database v5.3.23 requires illuminate/support 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
    - illuminate/database v5.3.4 requires illuminate/support 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.5.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.4.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.4.36 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.4.27 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.4.19 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.4.17 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.4.13 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.4.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.3.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.3.23 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.3.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.3.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for illuminate/database ^5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.2].
```

The vendor file is not made, and neither is the web folder that holds Wordpress. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. `composer require illuminate/support 5.5.*`
   This fails because it requires mbstring.

Result:

```
Problem 1
- illuminate/support v5.5.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- illuminate/support v5.5.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- Installation request for illuminate/support 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.5.0, v5.5.2].
```

2. I tried to install mbstring with `sudo yum install php-mbstring`. This didn't find a package, so I followed the steps in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278561/how-to-install-php-mbstring-on-centos-6-2) and switched from the mirror URL to  `baseurl=http://centos.intergenia.de/$releasever/updates/$basearch/`. This found a package but still failed. Here's where we get to the actual problem:

   **Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
   Error: php70u-json conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64**

From my Google research, I read that you need to install extra repositories for PHP7, but I have no idea what that means, or if that's what I need to do, or how to do it. I don't know who had this server space before me, but I know it had been upgraded to PHP 7 just before I got my hands on it.

3. Tried to update yum

   Disk Requirements:
   **At least 308MB more space needed on the / filesystem.**

I don't believe my issue is related to themosis, or Composer itself. I found [this possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221430/how-to-install-mbstring-extension), (`yum install php-mbstring --enablerepo=remi`) but don't want to completely wreck my server and I don't know how to undo that one if it's wrong. Is this Remi repository what I need to fix this?

Comment: What version of CentOS?

Comment: @AlexHowansky CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)  - will update question

Answer (score 0):

You need to install additional extensions is the same package namespace that the already installed packages:

- remi: php-mbstring (see the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/))
- webtatic: php70w-mbstring
- IUS: php70u-mbstring
- etc

Comment: Do you know how I'd check if any of those are already installed? I'm new to this.

Comment: $ sudo yum list | grep "\-mbstring"

php-mbstring.x86_64                     5.4.16-42.el7                  base     
php56u-mbstring.x86_64                  5.6.31-1.ius.centos7           ius      
php70u-mbstring.x86_64                  7.0.23-1.ius.centos7           ius      
php71u-mbstring.x86_64                  7.1.9-2.ius.centos7            ius